# Why does the legend not present data as a couple of brackets

Tags: r, scale, tmap

my scale bar is showing loads of categories, even when I try and put in breaks. I looked at my data base, and the variable im plotting ("49_or_more") appears to go in descending order, to a point, and then back up (i.e. I cannot order the values from highest to lowest and vice versa). why is this? I want my map to simply show a couple of brackets in the scale, but I dont know what to do

[image: map]

[the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukh6a.png)

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kKQ8.png)

I tried using breaks, this didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [don't upload images of data or code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead, include a [mre] that contains the code you have used and an example of your data, such as the output of `dput(head(mydata))`. As to the y axis labels, they look alphabetically ordered.